# How to create mongodb service in cloud foundry?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vagrant, cloud-foundry

I have cloud foundry deployed on vagrant machine.I want to push node js application that requires Mongodb service.But when I am trying to create mongodb service.But facing some firewall issue.

```
    vimal@rle0249:~/CloudFoundry/bosh-lite$ cf create-service mongodb default my-mongodb
    Creating service instance my-mongodb in org RelevanceLab / space RLCatalyst as admin...
    FAILED
    Error performing request: Get https://api.bosh-lite.com/v2/spaces/6ead0cb4-7a3f-4567-8142-5ffed76b928f/services?q=label%!A(MISSING)mongodb: dial tcp 10.244.0.34:443: i/o timeout
    TIP: If you are behind a firewall and require an HTTP proxy, verify the https_proxy environment variable is correctly set. Else, check your network connection.



     vimal@rle0249:~/CloudFoundry/bosh-lite$ cf marketplace
     Getting services from marketplace in org RelevanceLab / space    RLCatalyst as admin...
     FAILED
     Error performing request: Get https://api.bosh-lite.com/v2/spaces/6ead0cb4-7a3f-4567-8142-5ffed76b928f/services: dial tcp 10.244.0.34:443: i/o timeout
     TIP: If you are behind a firewall and require an HTTP proxy, verify the https_proxy environment variable is correctly set. Else, check your network connection.
     vimal@rle0249:~/CloudFoundry/bosh-lite$
```

```
    vimal@rle0249:~/CloudFoundry/bosh-lite/bin$ cf curl /v2/info
    {
       "name": "",
       "build": "",
       "support": "http://support.cloudfoundry.com",
       "version": 0,
       "description": "",
       "authorization_endpoint": "https://login.bosh-lite.com",
       "token_endpoint": "https://uaa.bosh-lite.com",
       "min_cli_version": null,
       "min_recommended_cli_version": null,
       "api_version": "2.51.0",
       "app_ssh_endpoint": "ssh.bosh-lite.com:2222",
       "app_ssh_host_key_fingerprint": "a6:d1:08:0b:b0:cb:9b:5f:c4:ba:44:2a:97:26:19:8a",
       "app_ssh_oauth_client": "ssh-proxy",
       "routing_endpoint": "https://api.bosh-lite.com/routing",
       "logging_endpoint": "wss://loggregator.bosh-lite.com:443",
       "doppler_logging_endpoint": "wss://doppler.bosh-lite.com:4443",
       "user": "e7ddc7f8-35e4-4b95-b9f5-b75a8073f18e"
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to make other requests to CF over https? what do you see if you run `cf curl /v2/info`?

Comment: Hi @DanHigham I have update the question with the output of command cf curl /v2/info .Thanks!!!

Comment: Assuming you can also successfully do a cf curl for the space in question `cf curl /v2/spaces/6ead0cb4-7a3f-4567-8142-5ffed76b928f`, I would start by using bosh to ssh to the cloud_controller job and watching the log for the cloud_controller api job whilst simultaneously making the call to `cf marketplace`

Comment: Thanks @DanHigham for the help.But I am not able to solve the issue.Can you please tell me how to add and deploy cloud foundry services.I have cloud foundry deployed on local machine.For services I have followed https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-services-contrib-release this document.

Comment: Hi, that is a really old bosh release, the services in which only support v1 of the services API which has been removed from CF since 228. Can I suggest you join the Slack CF community (http://slack.cloudfoundry.org/) and pose your questions about service provision with bosh-lite in an appropriate channel. The community there is huge and growing every day.

Comment: thank you for the reply @DanHigham and suggestion.I will definitely join the community and will try with new bosh release.